# R: recursive tree algorithm with a random split

Tags: r, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm interested in writing up a recursive binary tree algorithm. Given the following data where I've already sorted the covariate `x`

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(10, 20, 25, 35), y = c(-10.5, 6.5, 7.5, -7.5))
> mydata
   x     y
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5
3 25   7.5
4 35  -7.5
```

Suppose my final tree looks something like this:

```
          [-10.5, 6.5, 7.5, -7.5]
                /         \
          [-10.5]        [6.5, 7.5, -7.5]
                            /      \
                    [6.5, 7.5]       [ -7.5]
```

I want the final output of my function to return a list that contains all of the nodes:

```
> final_tree
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5
3 25   7.5
4 35  -7.5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5


[[2]][[2]]
   x     y
1 20   6.5
2 25   7.5
3 35  -7.5


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
   x     y
1 20   6.5
2 25   7.5


[[3]][[4]]
   x     y
1 35  -7.5
```

I am splitting my tree at every node with a random split by using `best_split_ind`. If `best_split_ind = 1`, then that means the 1st instance in the `node_parent` will end up in the `node_left`, and the rest end up in `node_right`. If `best_split_ind = 3`, then that means the first three instances in the `node_parent` will end up in the `node_left`, and the rest end up in `node_right`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# Initialize empty tree
create_empty_tree <- function(max_height) sapply(1:max_height, function(k) replicate(2**(k-1),c()))

# Create empty tree with max_height = 3
tree_struc <- create_empty_tree(max_height = 3)

grow_tree <- function(node_parent, max_height, tree_struc, height){
  # Sort x
  sorted_x <- sort(node_parent$x)

  # Determine best split 
  best_split_ind <- sample(1:(nrow(node_parent) - 1), 1)

  # Assign instances to left or right nodes
  group <- ifelse(node_parent$x <= node_parent$x[best_split_ind], "left", "right")
  node_left <- node_parent[which(group == "left"), ]
  node_right <- node_parent[which(group == "right"), ]

  # Recursive call on left and right nodes
  if(height < max_height){
  tree_struc[[height]] <- node_parent
  tree_struc[[height + 1]][[1]] <- grow_tree(node_parent = node_left, max_height = max_height, tree_struc = tree_struc, height = height + 1)
  tree_struc[[height + 1]][[2]] <- grow_tree(node_parent = node_right, max_height = max_height, tree_struc = tree_struc, height = height + 1)
  }

  return(tree_struc)
}

grow_tree(node_parent = mydata, max_height = 3, tree_struc = tree_struc, height = 1)
```

The resulting tree is not correct. I think it has to do with how I recursively called the function on the left and right child nodes. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood you, but you can simplify quite a bit here by using two functions that call each other recursively. There's no need to set up an initial container.

The first function is one that we don't even need to call manually, but will be called from inside our `grow_tree` function. It simply checks that it has not reached the maximum tree depth and that there are enough elements left to split. If so, it calls `grow_tree` on its contents. Otherwise, it returns its contents unchanged:

```r
conditional_split <- function(df, depth, max_depth)
{
  if(nrow(df) == 1 | depth == max_depth) return(df)
  else grow_tree(df, depth + 1, max_depth)
}
```

Our main function can then safely split the given data frame and recursively call `conditional_split` with `lapply`:

```r
grow_tree <- function(df, depth = 1, max_depth = 3)
{
  break_at <- sample(nrow(df) - 1, 1)
  branched <- list(left = df[1:break_at,], right = df[-seq(break_at),])
  lapply(branched, conditional_split, depth, max_depth)
}
```

I think this does what you're looking for:

```
grow_tree(mydata, max_depth = 3)
#> $left
#>    x     y
#> 1 10 -10.5
#> 
#> $right
#> $right$left
#> $right$left$left
#>    x   y
#> 2 20 6.5
#> 
#> $right$left$right
#>    x   y
#> 3 25 7.5
#> 
#> 
#> $right$right
#>    x    y
#> 4 35 -7.5
```

And you can change the maximum tree depth as easily as:

```r
grow_tree(mydata, max_depth = 2)
#> $left
#> $left$left
#>    x     y
#> 1 10 -10.5
#> 
#> $left$right
#>    x   y
#> 2 20 6.5
#> 3 25 7.5
#> 
#> 
#> $right
#>    x    y
#> 4 35 -7.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I interpret $right$left$left? I.e. which node is this on a tree?

Comment: @YQW it's simply the way it looks. Start at the root, take the right branch then the left branch of that node,  and then the left branch again to the next node. In your example at the top of your question, `[-10.5]` would be `$left` and `[-7.5]` would be `$right$right`

Comment: Thank you. As a side note, would it be possible to store what the `break_at` value was for each split?

Comment: @YQW that's almost right. Try `branched <- list(left = df[1:break_at,], right = df[-seq(break_at),]);
branched <-  lapply(branched, conditional_split, depth, max_depth); branched$break_at <- break_at; return(branched)`

Comment: Nice solution! It is smart to call functions interactively. Upvoted!

Comment: You too @ThomasIsCoding. Nice to see two recursion solutions to a problem. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below, where another custom function `rndsplit` was defined within `grow_tree`:

```
create_empty_tree <- function(max_height) sapply(1:max_height, function(k) replicate(2**(k-1),c()))
grow_tree <- function(node_parent,max_height = nrow(node_parent)) {
  rndsplit <- function(x) {
    if (is.null(x) || nrow(x) <= 1) return(list(c(),c()))
    ind <- sample(nrow(x)-1,1)
    list(x[1:ind,],x[-(1:ind),])
  }
  tree_struc <- create_empty_tree(max_height)
  tree_struc[[1]][[1]] <- node_parent
  for (i in 2:max_height) {
    tree_struc[[i]] <- unlist(lapply(tree_struc[[i-1]], rndsplit),recursive = FALSE)
  }
  tree_struc
}
```

**Example**

```
> grow_tree(mydata,3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5
3 25   7.5
4 35  -7.5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5

[[2]][[2]]
   x    y
3 25  7.5
4 35 -7.5


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5

[[3]][[2]]
   x   y
2 20 6.5

[[3]][[3]]
   x   y
3 25 7.5

[[3]][[4]]
   x    y
4 35 -7.5
```

and

```
> grow_tree(mydata)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5
3 25   7.5
4 35  -7.5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
   x     y
1 10 -10.5

[[2]][[2]]
   x    y
2 20  6.5
3 25  7.5
4 35 -7.5


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
   x   y
2 20 6.5

[[3]][[4]]
   x    y
3 25  7.5
4 35 -7.5


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
NULL

[[4]][[2]]
NULL

[[4]][[3]]
NULL

[[4]][[4]]
NULL

[[4]][[5]]
NULL

[[4]][[6]]
NULL

[[4]][[7]]
   x   y
3 25 7.5

[[4]][[8]]
   x    y
4 35 -7.5
```